# CSS of Grocery CRUD not loading

Tags: javascript, css, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I've installed Grocery-Crud and it works! But there is no any css files were loaded on page. I have standard code grocery_crud gives to users, so this is what I see, when I  want to see page's code:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/grocery.ru/assets/grocery_crud/themes/datatables/css/demo_table_jui.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/grocery.ru/assets/grocery_crud/css/ui/simple/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/grocery.ru/assets/grocery_crud/themes/datatables/css/datatables.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/grocery.ru/assets/grocery_crud/themes/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/grocery.ru/assets/grocery_crud/themes/datatables/extras/TableTools/media/css/TableTools.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/grocery.ru/assets/grocery_crud/css/jquery_plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" />

<script src="http://localhost/grocery.ru/assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/grocery.ru/assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery_plugins/ui/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/grocery.ru/assets/grocery_crud/themes/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/grocery.ru/assets/grocery_crud/themes/datatables/js/datatables-extras.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/grocery.ru/assets/grocery_crud/themes/datatables/js/datatables.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/grocery.ru/assets/grocery_crud/themes/datatables/extras/TableTools/media/js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/grocery.ru/assets/grocery_crud/themes/datatables/extras/TableTools/media/js/TableTools.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/grocery.ru/assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery_plugins/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/grocery.ru/assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery_plugins/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
```

Is that means, that it loads these files? I thought it so. And this is what I see when I connect with controller "examples.php" (I'm nor writing this code, 'cause it basic files in grocery's archive): http://rghost.ru/46695190

Comment: if you click the link for the files, can you view the file contents?

Comment: Yes, all pages works, I can see all information. But  information is not styled.

Comment: @Maria - when you open page -> click 'view source' -> and then check - CLICK links to css styles -> if you can't see content of css files (browser reports error), your paths are wrong.

Comment: Heh, I see beautiful path , so? What the next step?:)href="http://localhost/grocery.ru/assets/grocery_crud/themes/flexigrid/css/flexigrid.css"

Comment: Click on url -> if you see actual css -> path is ok, if not (and that's probably the case) - you have to change that paths... :)

Comment: The problem is that the path is right. I really don't understand what the hell is going on! :D

Comment: @maria, we kept on asking you, if you click the path of the css or javacript can you view the file contents? on the browser, even though you can see the path it does not mean it is correct!!!

Comment: Dear tomexsans.I really sorry for it misunderstanding. My English is bad, that's why sometimes I don't understand what people ask :( . About problem: I see the sourse of page, and when I clink on url of css(or js) file, it shows me error about redirect: "Ошибка 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)". Address was changed on "http://localhost/xampp/"